# Polymer: Changes not always flowing through a filter

Tags: data-binding, polymer

I've got an array that I'd like to display the top N elements from. This array is mutated and kept sorted by another component in my app.

I'm seeing a bug though such that if I display all of the array elements everything is fine. If I respond to my array changing by taking a copy of the array with `.slice()` and putting that in another field and displaying that field filtered for the top N elements, then everything if fine. But if I just display the original array filtered through for the top N elements then the DOM is never updated to changes.

Here's a codepen reduction of the bug that shows off the problem: http://codepen.io/rictic/pen/ienJK?editors=101

Full code:

```
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/platform.js"></script><script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/web-animations-js/web-animations.js"></script><link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<my-app></my-app>
<script>console.clear()</script>


<polymer-element name='my-app'>
  <template>
    <template if='{{results}}'>
      r in results
      <ul>
        <template repeat='{{ r in results }}'>
          <li>{{r.value}} - {{r.name}}</li>
        </template>
      </ul>

      r in processedResults | first(5)
      <ul>
        <template repeat='{{ r in processedResults | first(5) }}'>
          <li>{{r.value}} - {{r.name}}</li>
        </template>
      </ul>

      r in results | first(5)
      <ul>
        <template repeat='{{ r in results | first(5) }}'>
          <li>{{r.value}} - {{r.name}}</li>
        </template>
      </ul>

    </template>
  </template>
  <script>
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<script>
'use strict';

var names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charline', 'Daryl', 'Elise', 'Franz', 'Geraldine', 'Happsburg', 'Irene', 'Jerome'];

Polymer('my-app', {
  results: [{value: 10, name: 'root'}],
  first: function(a, k) {
    // A filterer to display the first k elements of an array.
    if (!a) {
      return a;
    }
    return a.slice(0, k);
  },
  domReady: function() {
    // Populate the results array.
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      this.results.push({value: i, name: names[i]});
    }

    // Once a second, mutate and sort the array
    setInterval(function() {
      var randomChoice = Math.round(Math.random() * (this.results.length - 1));
      this.results[randomChoice].value *= 2;
      this.results.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a.value != b.value) {
          return b.value - a.value;
        }
        return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
      });
    }.bind(this), 1000);
  },
  resultsChanged: function() {
    // Copy this.results into this.processedResults.
    this.processedResults = this.results.slice();
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Try initializing `results` in ready. If properties are array/object then they should be initialized there.

Comment: I could to make [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ctzhl?editors=101) work. But yes seems like a bug. It does not observe the changes to the object properies unless it is modified completely.

Comment: Good point about initializing `results` in ready. In my real app there's another element that gets `results` from doing a JSON.parse on a server response, then after it has given `results` to the element that corresponds to `my-app` above it continues to mutate the same array using `.push` and `.sort`. The behavior of the app is still the error as seen above. It is really interesting that your change fixed the problem, if I get some more time I guess I could step through the code to see where results is being observed and how that differs in each of these cases.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can setup results in the `created` callback and everything will work. Here's [an example CodePen](http://codepen.io/robdodson/pen/izvHK). The `created` callback is part of native custom elements and executes before `ready` (which is added by Polymer to know when various features like data binding are setup and ready to rock). I'm still fuzzy as to why you have to do it this way so I've asked a member of the team to explain it to me and I'll leave another comment when I know more :)

**edit**

After speaking with one of the authors of polymer-expressions, it sounds like your original code should have worked but filters are not currently rerunning if the object `model.results` points to is mutated. Instead they only rerun if the *path* to the object that `model.results` points to changes. This seems like a shortcoming of filters and we're looking into changing the behavior so it works as you would expect.

Comment: Ah, I should've thought to look for existing filed issues on polymer-expressions. Looks like other folks have discovered this judging from https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-expressions/issues/28 and the comments on https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-expressions/pull/23 . I've subscribed to those issues, thanks!

Comment: Specifically, the difference between `created` and `ready` is that `created` is called _before_ the attribute values set in markup are converted to property values. If you have a property that's an object or array, you should set the default value in `created`, which provides a type hint for Polymer when it converts the attribute value (a string) into a JavaScript object. The `ready` callback is invoked after properties are initialized from attributes, so  you can use those values in script. On the flip side, setting a property value in the `ready` callback overrides any value set in markup.